# Parsing HTML string in WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, html-parsing

I need to parse an HTML string that I receive from a server.

```
 <html>
 <head/>
 <body style="margin: 0;padding: 0">
    <a href="http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa   
/wa/viewSoftware?id=319737742&amp;mt=8&amp;uo=6" style="margin: 0;padding: 0"><img   
src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/sportschatter/postcard.jpg" style="margin: 0;padding: 
0"/></a>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the response I get from the server. I need to retrieve the `img` URL `https://s3.amazonaws.com/sportschatter/postcard.jpg` as well as the `href` part.
I have HTML Agility pack for WP7, but I don't know how to write the query to get this information. I tried something like this:

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument document = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
         document.LoadHtml(htmlString);


       var value  =  document.DocumentNode.Descendants("img src").
                                       Select(
                                           x =>
                                           x.InnerText);
```

This does not give me any value. I also tried `Regex`:

```
    string parseString = htmlstring;
        Regex expression = new Regex(@".*img src=(\d+).*$");
        Match match = expression.Match(parseString);
        MessageBox.Show(match.Groups[1].Value);
```

but this does not work either. Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Also i ahve seen lot of example of html Agility , most of them uses SelectNodes method, which is not present in WP7 verion of the library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You clearly misunderstood how you're meant to use the LINQ2XML syntax (without XPath, since XPath isn't supported on Windows Phone)

You need to do something like this instead:

```
var image = document.DocumentNode.Descendants("img").First()
var source = image.GetAttribute("src", "").Value;
```

Comment: thanks it worked , i have to change it slightly                       var image = document.DocumentNode.Descendants("img").First();
 var source = image.GetAttributeValue("src", "");  how do i get the text values which are generally in p tags

Comment: Use the `InnerHtml` or `InnerText` property.

Answer (score -1):

Use **HtmlAgilityPack** - do not use regex.

The 'query string' inside `Descendants` is an XPath, not CSS-like selector.

Here's an example: http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples
Here's some info about XPath: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086.aspx

Comment: HI Jakub , the example link uses  doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes, i am using HAPPhone version for htmlAgility pack, and it doesnt have DocumnentElemnt method.

Comment: XPath isn't supported on Windows Phone.